# Connecting to internet after clean install of ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: server, internet, ifconfig

I've installed ubuntu server on my computer. I would like to connect to the internet to download more software. I've done:

`ifconfig eth0 up`

so when I print

`ifconfig`

I can see the eth0 listed, but it doesn't have IP address. I tried to `dhclient` but that doesn't print anything.

What do I have to do first?

Comment: you have static ip or dynamic?

Comment: Right now, I dont have any. But there is DHCP on the server, where I want to connect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

edit the **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change the file to look like this

```
#The primary network interface -- use DHCP to find our address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

then try the following commands:

```
dhclient -r

/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: thx, I am getting, `postconf: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory`. Btw there is not some network manager that would care about that?

Comment: and its deprecated..

Comment: try this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix` It will fix it

Comment: Now it says (before too, sorry) `grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`. And it just hangs. Looks like we did some mistakes during install, didn't we?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

Comment: Ooooh man. I just realized I have two network cards and we configured the bad one :/. Now everything's working, thx

Comment: You are welcome and nevermind we've learn something new. tc